# Export PDF from SVG d3 chart using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, ecmascript-6, jspdf

I'm trying to export the SVG d3 chart to pdf file using jsPDF and JavaScript.

I'm using jsPDF to export pdf files. I'm able to export file but it has only a fewer content.

```
$("#exportPDF").click(() => {
      let svg = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById("Employement_Source"));
      let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      let doc = new jsPDF({orientation: 'l', unit: 'px'});
      let img = document.createElement("img");
      img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svg));
      img.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        doc.setFontSize(11);
        doc.text(5, 10, 'D3 Chart');
        doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), 'PNG', 10, 10, 200, 100);
        doc.save('download.pdf');
      };
    });
```

Expecting a full chart in the exported pdf file.

Comment: The constructor call looks shady! According to the [API docs](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html) the call takes an object comprising the options, not a list of individual options.

Comment: @altocumulus I have made the necessary changes to the code. Please review and let me know your thoughts. I'm not able to set the proper size which can hold all different charts with different dimensions. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've got the desired result and updated the solution by replacing the issue accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution to the issue I've faced recently. I've canvas dimensions so that I can get the complete chart.

```js
$("#exportPDF").click(() => {
      let svg = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById("Employement_Source"));
      let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      let svgSize = $(svg)[0];
      // let svgSize = $(svg)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
      canvas.width = svgSize.width.baseVal.value;
      canvas.height = svgSize.height.baseVal.value;

      let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      let doc = new jsPDF({
        orientation: 'l',
        unit: 'px'
      });
      let img = document.createElement("img");
      img.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        // console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        doc.setFontSize(11);
        doc.text(5, 10, 'D3 Chart');
        doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), 'PNG', 10, 10);
        doc.save('download.pdf');
      };
      img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svg));
    });
```